# Use storyboard in share extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios8-share-extension

The extension Share when we created it, is automatically created one file called mainInterface.storyboard, which in this case seems to be a kind of custom screen for the share Extension.

In my case I changed this screen and to my surprise when I select my application to give share, it besides pulling the custom screen, it also commonly pulls the original screen on the share (that with the text field two buttons).

How can I make to no push original screen, but push the custom screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your view controller is still a subclass of `SLComposeServiceViewController`. That class will always display the default share UI if you use it. If you don't want that UI, you should change your view controller to inherit from `UIViewController` instead.

Comment: Others Commands, Others problems, Your idea works very well, now If I open share extension with an image, how can I get the Image Url, and if in safari, how can I get the URL?

Comment: That is a totally different question (and one which is covered in Apple's docs and several web tutorials)